# Scrapy Installation on Ubuntu14.04

Tags: python, scrapy

I follow the Installation Guide on https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/install.html
but I failed the installation.When I pip install scrapy,it was failed to install in the end.

[image]

------Edit on 11:47---
I can not run the scrapy properly.

[image]

---When I run it----

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/scrapy", line 7, in <module>
    from scrapy.cmdline import execute
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 9, 
in <module>
    from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 7, 
in <module>
    from twisted.internet import reactor, defer
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/reactor.py", 
line 38, in <module>
    from twisted.internet import default
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/default.py", 
line 56, in <module>
    install = _getInstallFunction(platform)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/default.py", 
line 44, in _getInstallFunction
    from twisted.internet.epollreactor import install
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-
packages/twisted/internet/epollreactor.py", line 24, in <module>
    from twisted.internet import posixbase
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-
packages/twisted/internet/posixbase.py", line 18, in <module>
    from twisted.internet import error, udp, tcp
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/tcp.py", 
line 28, in <module>
    from twisted.internet._newtls import (
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/_newtls.py", 
line 21, in <module>
   from twisted.protocols.tls import TLSMemoryBIOFactory, 
TLSMemoryBIOProtocol
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/protocols/tls.py", 
line 63, in <module>
    from twisted.internet._sslverify import _setAcceptableProtocols
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-
packages/twisted/internet/_sslverify.py", line 38, in <module>
    TLSVersion.TLSv1_1: SSL.OP_NO_TLSv1_1,
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'OP_NO_TLSv1_1'
```

Comment: your user account doesn't have the permission, switch to root account.

Comment: thanks,but when I use root account to install this thing,it seems not to install properly.

Comment: When you say I can't run scrapy properly, what is happening? What error do you get when running scrapy?

Comment: I'm sorry to have not put the screen shot to my question.http://paste.ubuntu.com/25316842/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `pip install Scrapy`, do `sudo pip install Scrapy`

Alternatively, use [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/)

Comment: thanks,but when I use root account to install this thing,it seems not to install properly.

Comment: @DennisShaw Follow the described steps [here](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/2473), then it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be a PyOpenSSL issue.

Attempt:

```
sudo pip install -U pyOpenSSL
```